# Is it necessary to remove the metaClass after using mockDomain in Grails unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking, teardown

[mockDomain](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.html#mockDomain%28java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List%29) provides dynamic methods like `save()`, `validate()`, ... for a domain class.

Is it necessary to remove the meta classes for each class I mock using `mockDomain`?

```
class UserTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    protected void setUp()
    {
        super.setUp()
        mockDomain User
        mockDomain Address
    }

    protected void tearDown()
    {
        super.tearDown()
        def remove = GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.&removeMetaClass
        remove User
        remove Address
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do that. The mockDomain method calls `registerMetaClass`, which stashes away the current metaClass and substitutes a new one, so that on tearDown the test can restore the old metaClass for you. When you do need to add methods to a metaClass yourself, you can call registerMetaClass (before you add your changes, of course) and once it's done the test will do the cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Out of curiosity, what would lead you to believe that you would need to do that?

Comment: A discussion with a workmate. I was right and it's not necessary

Comment: I was right too, but I guess the other guys answer was better for you?

Comment: @Gregg: yes, you're right, and you were first. but answers with an explanation usually do better.